# Should I use Objects for Tiles?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I am making a small 2D game which has a character that can jump (side-scroller). Now the levels in the game are made from tiles (mario like?). Now my character can jump at the moment but he can't land (because the tiles are still non existant).

My question is, should I make the tiles instances of classes (Seems quite OO)? An alternative I came up with is just drawing the tiles into the level and making rectangles which hold there position, but I feel like this would make it quite hard to give them special attributes. Like: can be destroyed, is solid?

Anyone has any alternative solutions to tiles implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Of course.**

A tile is an entity in your program logic. Such entities naturally correspond to objects. There isn’t really a sensible alternative to that, although of course not every single type of entity has to be represented by its *own* class.

In a way, the question doesn’t even make sense, since the whole point of object orientation is that *everything* is an object. Your question was probably more along the lines of whether tiles should be represented by a class, though. But again, the answer would be yes: otherwise reasoning about your tile objects becomes hard: you would have *disjoint( data (coordinates, representation, actions) corresponding to a single tile. Because that data is disjoint, it would be hard to reason about the object coherently. You couldn’t write code which treats tiles as logical entities.

About your alternatives:

> An alternative I came up with is just drawing the tiles into the level and making rectangles which hold there position, but I feel like this would make it quite hard to give them special attributes. Like: can be destroyed, is solid?

You already noted the drawbacks. This isn’t really a sensible alterative at all, it would make trivial tasks very complex (or impossible).

> structs

Structs and classes are the same thing in C++ (except for irrelevant details for the purpose of this discussion).

> reading the tile from the screen

Like your first alternative, this one simply offers no benefits.

In a way this question is hard to reason about once you get the hang of programming, because (regardless of whether you are looking for an object-oriented solution or not), representing the tiles by objects isn’t even a *choice*, it’s automatic.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, as to: "not every single type of entity has to be represented by its own class" what would be the preferred way of implementation? Inheritance?

Comment: @Floris What I mean by that is simply this: say you have a database of people (e.g. employees at a company). Now you *could* represent their names by a class for `Name`, their age by a class for `Age` etc. But it’s probably simpler to represent their names by `string`s and their ages by `unsigned int`s. But still those are *objects*. In fact, in C++ parlance everything that resides in memory and has a type is an object, by definition. More generally (in object orientation), every entity that you reason about is an object.